# Is it possible to edit a crispy form using styles.css? Like change the background color, etc.? Because I can't make mine work. Thanks

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I am a beginner in studying Python Django and I am trying to create a login page for my website using crispy forms. But I can't control the styling of it, I am wondering if it is possible and if it is, how can I possibly do it? Thanks.

Here is the Django HTML codes:

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'users/register.css' %}">

<div class="register-container">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                Create An Acount
            </legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            Already Have An Account? 
            <a class="ml-2" href="#">Log In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

CSS:
base.css

```
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: radial-gradient(circle, 
              rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, 
              rgba(33,208,178,1) 100%);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're also using Bootstrap and so some standard  Bootstrap CSS might need to be over-ridden. Have you tried using `!important` on the relevent CSS? Eg `background: rgb(255,255,255) !important;`

Comment: Yes I already tried using !important but it still doesn't apply the styling :(( but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you can simply add javascript code which adds class to desired input field and then you can add styling for that class.

For e.g :-

```
# if you want to add styling to the username input then

# use this javascript
const inp_field = document.querySelector("#input_username"); # enter the id/class of that element
inp_field.classList.add("custom__css");
    
# css code
.custom__css {
    # whatever css you need
}
```

Comment: You can also use django forms, refer to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-XXvUENY_8

Comment: Thank you. I will try doing that.